# Is there a way to save received email + attachment all at once?

Tags: attachment, harmon.ie

Looking for a way to save a received email + the attachments (in different files) into SharePoint via harmon.ie, all at once.

For the sent emails, the dialog box allows to do that by checking the relevant options. However, if I'm not wrong, for the received emails I have to first save the message and then save the attachments, or viceversa, but I cannot do it at once.

Am I overlooking something obvious here? Haven't any other users come into this problem too?

It would be great if the dialog of the "save message" box allowed to save the attachments as well, instead of having to do it into two separate operations. If there's not a way to do it now, can harmon.ie consider to implement this feature for next releases?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[EDIT] I'm asking for this feature not only because it's time consuming having to do it separately but because some of my users just "forget" to save the attachments when they have already saved the message, thinking they've done it all at once. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When saving the email (and when the option to ask to save email is set) the whole email will be always be saved (i.e. with attachments), however you have the option to aslo select the attachment(s) to upload along with the email (but the email is uploaded with the attachment(s))
The option to replace attachment with links is however not available when saving message from Inbox or any other folder (or when using Save Message button)

If you set the option to replace attachment with links (see screen shot at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrgxsriww2h81hx/replace.png?dl=0), the email will be saved without the attachment but will contain the link to the attachment in SharePoint.
This is close to your initial request.

---- Jean